# How can I convert a List<String> to String []?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this String

```
List<String> params = ['A','B','C'];
```

I want to convert this to `"['A']['B']['C']"`
How can I convert this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```dart
void main(){
  List<String> params = ['A','B','C'];
  final out = params.map((e) => "['$e']").join();
  print(out);
}
```

Prints:

```
['A']['B']['C']
```

Comment: My purpose is to access JSON vai field name  [data/splashPage]

Working solution
`Map jsonData = jsonDecode(snap.data ?? "");
Map<String, dynamic> splashPageJson = jsonData['data']['splashPage'];
print(splashPageJson);
`

Comment: Not working 


`List<String> params = ['data','splashPage'];
final out = params.map((e) => "['$e']").join();
Map jsonData = jsonDecode(snap.data ?? "");

Map<String, dynamic> splashPageJson = '${jsonData}$out' as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(splashPageJson);
`

How to solve it?

Comment: @SK- It's hard to tell within the comment section. Please consider asking as a _new_ question on Stack Oveflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079040/how-to-access-json-via-field

Answer (score 0):

- I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it can be achieved like this

```
    List<String> params = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    List.generate(
        params.length, (index) => params[index] = '''['${params[index]}']''');
    var str = '';
    params.forEach((item) => str += item);
    print(str);
```

Comment: // ['A']['B']['C']

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
  List<String> params = ['A','B','C'];
  List newParams = [];
  for(var item in params){
    newParams.add([item]);
  }
  String stringParams = newParams.toString();
  String noBracketParams = stringParams.substring( 1, stringParams.length - 1 );
  String noCommasParams = noBracketParams.replaceAll(',', '');
  print(noCommasParams);
```