# How to access JSON via field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON

jsonData

```
{
    "data": {
      "splashPage": {
        "title": "Splash"
      },
      "homePage": {
        "title": "Home"
      }
    }
}
```

```
List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage']; 
final out = accessField.map((e) => "['$e']").join();
Map jsonMapData = jsonDecode(jsonData); 
Map<String, dynamic> splashPageJson = '${jsonMapData}$out' as Map<String, dynamic>; 
print(splashPageJson);
```

I got an error can't access to splashPage.

```
_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)
```

How can I access to splashPage from JSON?

Note: accessField is dynamic value

If I want to access splashPage, declaration

```
    accessField = ['data','splashPage'];
```

If I want to access homePage, declaration

```
    accessField = ['data','homePage'];
```

Comment: what error you got？

Comment: _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Comment: how about `Map jsonMapData = jsonDecode(jsonData); print(jsonMapData["data"]["splashPage"]["title])` ?

Comment: It's work  as  `print(jsonMapData["data"]["splashPage"]["title]);`
but my accessField is dynamic. base on user what they want to access, it's canbe splashPage or homePage field.

Comment: Tell me what kind of data you want to convert into, and what does your json data look like?

Comment: jsonData is like this?  var jsonData = '{"title":"Test"}';

Comment: @bakboem
My purpose is i can access any data from JSON base on my 
`List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage']; `

Comment: @bakboem If i want to access homePage I just add 
`accessField = ['data','homePage'];`

Comment: @bakboem
JSON data is above

Comment: @ bakboem
`{
    "data": {
      "splashPage": {
        "title": "Splash"
      },
      "homePage": {
        "title": "Home"
      }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
var jsonData = {
    "data": {
      "splashPage": {
        "title": "Splash"
      },
      "homePage": {
        "title": "Home"
      }
    }
}

Map jsonMapData = jsonDecode(jsonData); 

List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage'];

Map<String, dynamic> requiredResult = jsonMapData[accessField[0]][accessField[1]];
```

Comment: How if I want to access to splashPage title. so I need to change everytime like 
`List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage','title'];
Map<String, dynamic> requiredResult = jsonMapData[accessField[0]][accessField[1]][accessField[3]];
`

Not help

Comment: `List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage'];` is dynamic so I need to join the field first and map with jsonData

`final out = accessField.map((e) => "['$e']").join();
Map jsonMapData = jsonDecode(jsonData); 
Map<String, dynamic> splashPageJson = '${jsonMapData}$out' as Map<String, dynamic>; 
print(splashPageJson);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

First import:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

To store JSON into the map:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode('{"data":{"splashPage":{"title":"Splash"},"homePage":{"title":"Home"}}}');
```

To print your requirement:

```
print(map["data"]["splashPage"]["title"]);
```

Comment: accessField is dynamic base on user want to access. it can be 

`List<String> accessField = ['data','splashPage']; 
List<String> accessField = ['data','homePage']; 
`

Comment: so access via field
`print(map["data"]["splashPage"]["title"]);`
not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Code for your Model:

```
class Model {
  Model({
    this.data,
  });

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json["data"] != null ? Data.fromJson(json["data"]) : null;
  }
  Data? data;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (data != null) {
      map["data"] = data?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.splashPage,
    this.homePage,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    splashPage = json["splashPage"] != null
        ? SplashPage.fromJson(json["splashPage"])
        : null;
    homePage =
        json["homePage"] != null ? HomePage.fromJson(json["homePage"]) : null;
  }
  SplashPage? splashPage;
  HomePage? homePage;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (splashPage != null) {
      map["splashPage"] = splashPage?.toJson();
    }
    if (homePage != null) {
      map["homePage"] = homePage?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

class HomePage {
  HomePage({
    this.title,
  });

  HomePage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json["title"];
  }
  String? title;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["title"] = title;
    return map;
  }
}

class SplashPage {
  SplashPage({
    this.title,
  });

  SplashPage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json["title"];
  }
  String? title;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["title"] = title;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Code for your usage:

```
final Model model = Model.fromJson(
    json.decode(
      '{"data":{"splashPage":{"title":"Splash"},"homePage":{"title":"Home"}}}',
    ),
  );


print(model.data?.splashPage?.title ?? "");
print(model.data?.homePage?.title ?? "");
```

Don't forgot to import:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Comment: my JSON is dynamic, I can't create a Model for an interceptor.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

- This is a question about conversion of Json data format to native data model. If you publish the Json data earlier, the problem may not be so complicated
- try this.

```
  void test() {
    var json =
        '{"data":{"splashPage":{"title":"Splash"},"homePage":{"title":"Home"}}}';
    var map = jsonDecode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var model = DataResponseModel.fromJson(map);
    pr(model.data?.homePage?.title); // Home
    pr(model.data?.splashPage?.title); // Splash
  }



class TitleModel {
  String? title;
  TitleModel({required this.title});
  factory TitleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      TitleModel(title: map['title']);
}

class DataModel {
  TitleModel? splashPage;
  TitleModel? homePage;
  DataModel({required this.splashPage, this.homePage});
  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) => DataModel(
        splashPage: TitleModel.fromJson(map['splashPage']),
        homePage: TitleModel.fromJson(map['homePage']),
      );
}

class DataResponseModel {
  DataModel? data;
  DataResponseModel({required this.data});
  factory DataResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      DataResponseModel(
        data: DataModel.fromJson(map['data']),
      );
}
```